# SUBSTR in oracle not working when there is line break in the string

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay so I am working with a database that has data in many formats. I was asked to split a string into 3 columns by 150 length in each column

The data in the table is stored as this

```
'1. These MSDS, Declaration and SGS are to post to Environment database.
        The MSDS serial number is MCSPRINGH0403021.
        The Declaration serial number is DCSPRINGH0403004.
        The SGS serial number is TCSPRINGH0403007.
    2. It's required to follow specification drawing with Rev.A0 for MP.
        The change for Rev.A0 is only change Rev."PA4" to "A0"  on silkscreen printing.


        '
```

I want to split this data into 3 columns , COL1, COL2, COL3

When I use this query it works fine.

```
SELECT SUBSTR('1. These MSDS, Declaration and SGS are to post to Environment database.
    The MSDS serial number is MCSPRINGH0403021.
    The Declaration serial number is DCSPRINGH0403004.
    The SGS serial number is TCSPRINGH0403007.
2. It''s required to follow specification drawing with Rev.A0 for MP.
    The change for Rev.A0 is only change Rev."PA4" to "A0"  on silkscreen printing.


    ', 1, 140) col1, 
    SUBSTR('1. These MSDS, Declaration and SGS are to post to Environment database.
    The MSDS serial number is MCSPRINGH0403021.
    The Declaration serial number is DCSPRINGH0403004.
    The SGS serial number is TCSPRINGH0403007.
2. It''s required to follow specification drawing with Rev.A0 for MP.
    The change for Rev.A0 is only change Rev."PA4" to "A0"  on silkscreen printing.


    ', 141, 280) col2,
    SUBSTR('1. These MSDS, Declaration and SGS are to post to Environment database.
    The MSDS serial number is MCSPRINGH0403021.
    The Declaration serial number is DCSPRINGH0403004.
    The SGS serial number is TCSPRINGH0403007.
2. It''s required to follow specification drawing with Rev.A0 for MP.
    The change for Rev.A0 is only change Rev."PA4" to "A0"  on silkscreen printing.


    ', 281, 420) col3 FROM DUAL
```

but I had to replace `It's` with `It''s`. How do I replace when the value is stored in column but that will not count `'` as a character and will eventually return wrong count. Also when there is a line break I want it to be take as 2 character `/b`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you actually represent the data as a column in a query or DML command then you shouldn't have that problem. In other words, when you do this:

```
select original_col,
       substr(original_col,1,140) col1,
       substr(original_col,141,140) col2,
       substr(original_col,281,140) col3
  from table;
```

it should work fine. You only have to worry about escaping special characters when you are typing in the literal text yourself, as in your example.

Also, be aware the the second number in substr is the length of the string, not the ending position of the segment, so if you want 140 characters, this should *always* be 140. From the documentation, "The SUBSTR functions return a portion of char, beginning at character position, substring_length characters long."

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E

Comment: That's what I am confused about. It's returning 245 characters for Col2 when I check with `Length()` function.

Comment: The second parameter in substr isn't the ending position in the string, it's the number of characters to include in the segment from the point where you started, so it should always be 140. When you said "substr(col,141,280)" you told Oracle to start at position 141 and include the _next_ 280 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry when you are going to use the column name in `substr` as issue that you are facing is in string creation, not in `substr`.

While using string, You can use the **quoted string** as follows:

```
q'<delimiter><Your string with><delimeter>'
```

You can use special characters as a delimiter.

```
q'#That's it#' -- > That's it
```

You must learn about quoted string from oracle documents.

You can also use two single quotes and that will be considered as a single quote while preparing the string. so your

```
That''s it --> That's it
```

Answer (score 0):

Use q-quoting mechanism. `val_1` is what you currently do, `val_2` is a *new* suggestion:

```
SQL> select substr( '1. This is MSDS, it''s something special' , 1, 30) val_1,
  2         substr(q'[1. This is MSDS, it's something special]', 1, 30) val_2
  3  from dual;

VAL_1                          VAL_2
------------------------------ ------------------------------
1. This is MSDS, it's somethin 1. This is MSDS, it's somethin

SQL>
```

Comment: how do use this q-quoting on a column ?
`select substr(qCOLUMA, 141, 280) from dual` ?

Comment: Why would you use it on a column? I presume you didn't store two consecutive single quotes into a column, did you?

Comment: This string is stored in a column, COLUMNA. I want to split that column into 3 columns. When I use substr it is returning 245 characters for `SUBSTR(COLUMNA, 141, 280)`, which it shouldn't

Comment: Are there any multibyte characters involved? LENGTH will return length of a string in *bytes*. If you use e.g. Chinese characters, every character occupies 3 bytes so ...

Comment: it returned 245 characters because you told it to include up to 280 characters in the substr command.

Comment: Ah, yes, @pmdba; we do need someone smart here. Thank you for noticing!